# Lower bound on the probability that a sum of bivariate Bernoulli variables are equal to their mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $(X^{(i)})_{i \in [n]}$ be independent identically distributed 2-dimensional Bernoulli variables, with $\Pr[X^{(i)} = (a, b)] = p_{a, b}$ for every $a, b \in \{0, 1\}$. I then want to lower bound the probability that the sum is equal to the mean, that is, I want to lower bound
$$
  \Pr[\sum_{i \in [n]}X^{(i)} = E[\sum_{i \in [n]} X^{(i)}]] \; .
$$
Clearly, this requires that $E[\sum_{i \in [n]} X^{(i)}_j]$ is an integer for $j \in \{1, 2\}$. If the two coordinates are independent then the probability splits into two products of 1-dimensional Bernoulli variables which is easy to handle. The problem is when the two coordinates are correlated.

For 1-dimensional Bernoulli variables, $(Y_i)_{i \in [n]}$, with $E[Y] = p$, we get that
$$
  \Pr[\sum_{i \in [n]} Y_i = pn]
  = \binom{n}{pn} p^{pn}(1-p)^{n - pn}
  \ge \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}
  \ge \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
where we have used that $\binom{n}{pn} \ge \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}n^n e^{-n}}{(e \sqrt{pn} (pn)^{pn} e^{-pn}) \cdot (e \sqrt{n - pn} (n - pn)^{n - pn} e^{-n - pn})}$ which follows from the approximation $\sqrt{2\pi k} k^k e^{-k} \le k! \le e \sqrt{k} k^k e^{-k}$. A reference for this approximation is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation.

My hope is that one can prove something similar in the 2-dimensional case, namely, that there exists a constants $\gamma$ and $C$, such that,
$$
  \Pr[\sum_{i \in [n]}X^{(i)} = E[\sum_{i \in [n]} X^{(i)}]] \ge C n^{-\gamma} \; .
$$

Comment: What properties do you require of this lower bound? Is the almost trivial lower bound $\min\{p_{a,b}\}^n$ sufficient?

Comment: @Greg What about polynomial in $n$?

Comment: I think this can be calculated exactly as a single sum, of $\le n$ terms, each term involving binomial coefficients...  So Greg is very astute in asking what _quality_ lower bound are you looking for?

Comment: @antkam To get a simple lower bound you could identify the largest term of the sum, but is it clear which term is the largest? I think the issue is the roundings off you have to do in that process.

Comment: @ThomasAhle - my point, and I _think_ Greg's point, is that there is a wide range from the exact (non-closed form, summation-and-${n \choose r}$-based) solution to something trivial, and we need the OP to give us more insight into what _quality_ of bound is being requested.  E.g. maybe tell us more about the application (if any) which led to asking this question?

Comment: I have updated the question to be more precise about the quality of the lower bound. I would hope to prove that there exists  constants, $\gamma$ and $C$, such that, the probability is lower bounded by $C n^{-\gamma}$.